# Svelte and form with dynamic inputs

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit

I want to create a form to retrieve a person's name and country, but with the possibility of adding several lines of the same type on client side before submitting the form. Here is the code I use.

```
/* This is my Person.svelte component file */

<script>
  export let uniqueId;
</script>

<div>
  <label for="firstname{uniqueId}">Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="firstname{uniqueId}" name="firstname[]" />

  <label for="country{uniqueId}">Country</label>
  <input type="text" id="country{uniqueId}" name="country[]" />
/>
</div>


/* And this is the +page.svelte file */

<script>
import Person from "./Person.svelte";
import { onMount } from "svelte";

let idCount = 0;

const addPerson = () => {
  idCount++;
  const Person = new Person({
    props: {
        uniqueId: idCount,
    },
    target: PersonForm,
    });
  };

  onMount(() => {
  const PersonForm = document.getElementById("PersonForm");
});
</script>


<form method="POST" id="PersonForm">
<Person uniqueId={idCount} />
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<button on:click={addPerson}>Add a person</button>
```

I expect to have an array by putting [] in the input names but that doesn't work : in the back-end I receive something like this where I have the same name for each data :

> ```
> [
> { name: 'firstname[]', value: 'John' },
> { name: 'country[]', value: 'Texas' },
> { name: 'firstname[]', value: 'James' },
> { name: 'country[]', value: 'New York' }
> ]
> ```

Here's the backend code to get the form data :

```
export const actions = {
    default: async ({request}) => {
        const data = await request.formData();
        console.log("Data : ", data);
        console.log(request.formData);
    }
};
```

Do you have any ideas to  get structured data from the form ?

Comment: I cant find any documentation on the bracket notation. Can you point me to it? Or why are you expecting this to work?

Comment: I saw this behavior by searching on Google, for example here :
https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/php/html-php-form-input-as-array.html
But it seems to work on some PHP or specific framework, not a standard beahavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I expect to have an array by putting [] in the input names but that doesn't work

That assumption is just wrong. Some server frameworks have automatic parsing of data to objects, but SvelteKit simply does not.

The integration of this logic in SvelteKit has been rejected as a userland issue, so if you want to parse syntax like this, you will have to do it yourself or find a library that does it for you.

Comment: Thanks, I better understand. What do you think about adding the uniqueId to each name, so I get this in the backend :
`
[
{ name: 'firstname1', value: 'John' },
{ name: 'country1', value: 'Texas' },
{ name: 'firstname2', value: 'James' },
{ name: 'country2', value: 'New York' }
]
`
then I'll create a function to split this object into distinct objects. This is what I had in mind first but I thought using name[] was the good way...

Comment: If the order is fixed, I would not bother with that. Would get all lists for each parameter via [`getAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/getAll), then use a loop and index into each list to get values that belong together.

Comment: Thanks for the getAll tip. This resolved my problem !